# 1-Form Criterion for Smooth Distribution

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

I am reading the following proof on page 493 of the book [Introduction to Smooth Manifolds of John M. Lee](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441999817)

[image]

In the second sentence of the proof, he claimed that the forms $\omega^1,..., \omega^{n-k}$ are independent on $U$ for dimensional reasons. What did he mean by "dimensional reasons"? I suppose there is something related to rank-nullity theorem, but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: "Dimensional reasons" refer to the fact $k+(n-k)=n$.

Comment: @Cave Johnson Can you please give more details? Which is the map in rank-nullity theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will make it clearer: put the forms together into one linear operator
$$
\Omega :TM\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n-k} \\
\Omega(X) := (\omega^1(X),\ldots,\omega^{n-k}(X)).
$$
Then pointwise
$$
\operatorname{Ker} \Omega = \bigcap_{i=1}^{n-k}\operatorname{Ker}\omega^i = D.
$$
So $\dim\operatorname{Ker}\Omega = \dim D = k$, and hence by rank-nullity
$$
\dim\operatorname{Im}\Omega = \dim TM - \dim\operatorname{Ker}\Omega = n-k.
$$
So $\Omega$ is surjective at each point of $U$, implying that the $\omega^i$ are linearly independent.